# Generalization of Grassmann manifold to include translations?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds

I came across a certain generalization of Grassmann manifolds and was wondering what work if any has been done on it.  If you take the space of $n\times p$ real matrices, $n>p$, and define an equivalence relationship

$A\sim B \Leftrightarrow \exists M\in GL(p)\mid AM=B$

where $GL(p)$ is the space of invertible $p\times p$ real matrices, then the quotient space defined by this relation is the space of all $p$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, called the Grassmann manifold $Gr(n,p)$.

If you generalize this equivalence relation to also include the addition of a constant to each column:

$A\sim B \Leftrightarrow \exists M\in GL(p), x \in \mathbb{R}^p\mid (A1_n)\left(\begin{array}{c}M\\x^T\end{array}\right)=B$

what is the manifold given by the corresponding quotient space?  Does it have a name?  Are there analytic solutions for the geodesics on this manifold, like there are for Grassmann manifolds?

---

This came up while trying to figure out how to maximize Gaussian mutual information under certain constraints.  If you have two data matrices $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times T}$ and $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times T}$, then the empirical Gaussian mutual information between them can be computed as

$\hat{I}[X;Y] = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{log}|M_nXX^TM_n^T| - \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{log}|M_nXX^TM_n^T-M_nXY^TM_m^T(M_mYY^TM_m^T)^{-1}M_mYX^TM_n^T|$

where $M_n:=I_n-1_{n\times n}/n$ is the matrix that subtracts the mean from each row of a matrix. This function is invariant under left multiplication of $X$ or $Y$ by an arbitrary matrix in $GL(n)$ or $GL(m)$ respectively, but also under addition of an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ to each column.  I'd like to do optimization of this function directly in the quotient space defined by this equivalence relationship, instead of on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times T} \times \mathbb{R}^{m\times T}$, which is precisely the Cartesian product of the manifold I defined above.

---

Edit: I realized my previous comment about this manifold being larger than $Gr(n,p)$ is wrong.  The equivalence relation is more general than the equivalence relation for $Gr(n,p)$, so the manifold is smaller.  It also occurs to me that the construction I described can be given as $GL(n)/(GL(n-p)\times Aff(p)) = GL(n)/(GL(n-p)\times (\mathbb{R}^p \rtimes GL(p)))$ where $Aff(p)$ is the $p$ dimensional affine space.  I believe this is equivalent to $O(n)/(O(n-p)\times(\mathbb{R}^p \rtimes O(p))$ where $O(n)$ is the group of $n$ dimensional orthogonal matrices, since $Gr(n,p)$ can be constructed as $O(n)/(O(n-p)\times O(p))$.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the Grassmannian $Gr(n-1,p)$. You can use the freedom to add a constant to each column to make the last entry in each column be $0$, and then you are looking at $(n-1) \times p$ matrices modulo $GL_p$.